# Ubuntu 13.04 UEFI problems

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

Note: I've had problems with all variants of *Buntu

EDIT: Tried Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 and it just hangs during UEFI boot, just a black screen I can type on til it freezes.

EDIT 2: Tried Lubuntu 13.04 and Kubuntu 13.04 again, same problem. Tried everything through Legacy MBR boot, same problem, all with the live media. Now it just hangs and won't do anything.

So I download Ubuntu 13.04 first, and when i go to boot the live cd through UEFI, it hangs for a bit then spams and after all of that, it finally boots into the live environment. It installs fine, no problems there. Then it goes to boot the installation, and it hangs and has a waiting for root device error, and takes me to a busybox console.  after a minute or so, it ALSO spams an modprobe error !, and after it's stops spamming that, i can type "exit" and it goes into ubuntu, and everything seems alright after.

Then Kubuntu 13.04, won't finish installing, it keeps failing at the bootloader deployment, first it was this grub-dummy package, then it failed with GRUB-EFI. I really have no idea what to do, Ubuntu 13.04 DOES work, but why am I having these boot problems?

Hardware:
Asus Republic of Gamers Crosshair V Formula Z AMD motherboard
AMD FX-8350
Radeon HD 7870
8GB DDR3-2133
120GB Samsung SSD
1TB Seagate Barracuda
Belkin Wireless N Wifi adapter
Built in audio

It won't let me put links and stuff because "i dont have enough reputation" so no idea how to get help for my problem when I can't show it.

Images:
[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]
[image: Picture 4]
[image: Picture 5]

Comment: Please someone help? I can't use any of the ubuntu variants.

Comment: Can't you disable UEFI? My laptop BIOS gives me the option of loading a "legacy ROM".

Comment: I can actually, but that would get rid of the point of using Windows 7 on UEFI. I forgot to include that Windows 7 is installed on UEFI aswell, so it's actually a dual boot.  :x

Comment: I couldn't even run the Ubuntu 13.04 installer with UEFI. I just get a corrupted/scrambled setup screen.

Comment: Just an update, I actually did a secure erase on my SSD, and tried installing in Legacy boot, for MBR and for every variant, it still does the same thing. Since I have rep above 10 now I can post my pictures so everyone can see what i mean.

Comment: Sigh. I've even posted on Ubuntu forums now, and still no one knows whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

Formatted my data drive but it works now, no more hanging with `modprobe` things, and no more waiting for root device. But now I have to reinstall all my stuff when I get windows again.

Comment: "You guys probably should look into that?" This forum primarily contains questions and answers by *users*. If you want to contact the developers, you can file a bug report, as detailed here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Answer (score 0):

so, one thing to take note of is that you probably have CSM set to on in your bios. This is the secure boot and locks out linux from certain things when trying to boot in EFI mode. If you want more information, look up crosshair V formula-Z and secure boot in a google search.

There is tons of information on it. Sadly, the regular formula is not quite the same and does not have this option (I have formula, not Z) and I have been dredging the net for more information on how to boot in efi mode as the bios is different and I kept running accross formula-z answers.

Hope that's somewhat helpful.